# Functional dependency not detected for some columns

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Here's a simple example schema:

[image: ERD]

```
CREATE TABLE parents (
  parent_id INT,
  type text null,
  PRIMARY KEY (parent_id)
);

CREATE TABLE children (
  child_id INT,
  parent_id INT,
  name text,
  PRIMARY KEY (child_id)
);

INSERT INTO parents (parent_id, type) VALUES (1, null);
INSERT INTO children (child_id, parent_id, name) VALUES (1, 1, 'foo');
```

This query works:

```
SELECT child_id
FROM children
JOIN parents USING (parent_id)
GROUP BY child_id, parent_id
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5idZtVXgoEqoUHrr85RW1p/0)

If I change that to `SELECT child_id, name` it still works, as it should because `name` is functionally dependent on `child_id` and `child_id` is in the GROUP BY clause.

Now if I change it to `SELECT child_id, type` I think it should still work, because `type` is functionally dependent on `parent_id` and `parent_id` is in the GROUP BY clause. But instead I get an error message:

> column "parents.type" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

What's the difference? Does it have anything to do with the JOIN?

Comment: Error message is quite explicit. You should add `parents.type` to select clause.

Comment: It says I should add it to the *GROUP BY clause* and I don't understand *why*. `parent_id` is already there and the same doesn't happen with the `name` column.

Comment: Because GROUP BY requires same columns in SELECT clause OR you can add AGGREGATES.http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/

Comment: No, since 9.1 [it doesn't](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/e49ae8d3bc588294d07ce1a1272b31718cfca5ef), which is why adding the `name` column to the SELECT but not to the GROUP  BY works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what is the difference.

When I write

```
SELECT child_id, type
FROM children
JOIN parents USING (parent_id)
GROUP BY child_id, parent_id
```

Postgres seems to assume I mean `GROUP BY child_id, children.parent_id` and even though those two are guaranteed to be identical by the JOIN, they don't seem to count as functionally dependent. If instead I write

```
SELECT child_id, type
FROM children
JOIN parents USING (parent_id)
GROUP BY child_id, parents.parent_id
```

Postgres recognizes the functional dependency and allows `type` to be in the SELECT expression.